# Why does a setTimeout function solve my Marionette ItemView/CollectionView DOM scope issue?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, raphael

I do have the following setup:

```
    var LayerItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

    tagName: 'li',
    className: 'stage-layer',
    template: '#layer-item-tpl',

    initialize: function() {
           $(this.el).attr('id' 'layer-'+this.model.id);
    },

    onRender: function() {
    App.vent.trigger('layer:rendered', this.model);
    }

});
```

As I believed, the DOM element layer-[id] should now be available. The eventHandler then creates a Raphael canvas for each model to the newly created DOM elements like so:

```
var paper1 = new Raphael(document.getElementById('layer-1'), 896,504);  
var paper2 = new Raphael(document.getElementById('layer-2'), 896,504);  
var paper3 = new Raphael(document.getElementById('layer-3'), 896,504);  
etc.
```

But I get an error back from Raphael:
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

which tells me the elements with layer-ids are not yet available in the DOM.
I solve the problem with a simple setTimeout (kind of does this):

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var paper1 = new Raphael(document.getElementById('layer-1'), 896,504);  
  var paper2 = new Raphael(document.getElementById('layer-2'), 896,504);  
  var paper3 = new Raphael(document.getElementById('layer-3'), 896,504);    
},0);
```

I don't feel comfortable with this. Could it be right practice? I would like to understand why this is working and whether it is good practice

Comment: How is the code called? Stick it into a `$(document).ready(function(){});`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is deceiving because at first glance someone might think that

```
var paper1 = new Raphael(document.getElementById('layer-1'), 896,504);  
var paper2 = new Raphael(document.getElementById('layer-2'), 896,504);  
var paper3 = new Raphael(document.getElementById('layer-3'), 896,504);
```

and

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var paper1 = new Raphael(document.getElementById('layer-1'), 896,504);  
  var paper2 = new Raphael(document.getElementById('layer-2'), 896,504);  
  var paper3 = new Raphael(document.getElementById('layer-3'), 896,504);    
},0);
```

are the same. When, in actuality they're very different.

What makes these two blocks of code different is a consequence of Javascript being a single-threaded language. Any `setTimeout` functions created are not called exactly when the timer reaches 0 in setTimeout. It will be executed, **approximately**, in that time frame. First Javascript will continue executing the current block of code that it's in.

So `setTimeout` in your situation, is being executed **after** the thread is finished in the current block of code that its in.

A good reference, and a lot more detailed information, is available [here](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/). Written by John Resig (jQuery).

Comment: No, its not good practice because its a sort of unexpected result. It's difficult to determine exactly when that function is executed since it is put into the Javascript 'queue' thus executed when the current block of code is finished. Don't you think that would make it difficult to debug later or even for another programmer to figure out what's going on. I think you just need to declare those 'papers', somewhere else in your code. Try cutting and pasting into different parts of the code to find out where it is accessible; IMO you're declaring it in the wrong place in your code.

Comment: Oh, and as bmorris suggested, you could try putting the code in `$(document).ready(function(){});` If you have found this helpful/answer your question, feel free to mark as an answer. Just saying. :)

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){})` does not make any difference, still get the Error back

Comment: @lunacafu Ok well I won't leave you hanging :P. If you could post more code or make a well laid out jsFiddle I could take a look tomorrow; I already put some time in, might as well finish the job.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I have setup 2 jsfiddles to simulate my App, http://jsfiddle.net/pbohny/new46/ has timeout and produces the Error, while this one behaves http://jsfiddle.net/pbohny/fUxqE/

Comment: I have figured out the problem. You are trying to work with those elements before they have been rendered to the page. If you use `$('body').html()` in the `PaperList.createPaper` function, you will see that those li elements have not been rendered yet. That is why the `setTimeout` function fixes it because it basically appends the request to the end of the code block. You need to ensure those elements are rendered properly first.

Comment: The reason this happens: In `CreatorApp.initSubApp` you call `MyApp.CreatorApp.PaperList.showPapers(CreatorApp.Papers)` which, *should* render the papers to the document, at least that's what you're probably thinking. What happens is rather that the functions for 'PaperList' are called: `initialize()` and `onRender()` before that `showPapers` function is called. In the `onRender()` you have created a trigger event. The function in `app.js` fires, directing the thread to `createPapers` before they have been effectively rendered to the page. My suggestion: put the rendering code in `onRender()`